# Markdown plugin in pycharm puts bullet points automatically

Tags: pycharm, markdown

I am typing along in a bulletted section of a `markdown` file in `pycharm` editor and a line is getting long. I hit return and `pycharm` is "helpfully" adding a bullet automatically:

- analytics services needs to first provide capability of more frequent and timely reporting to convince
- suppliers to provide more timely updates  `[Note the star/asterisk was inserted by pycharm ..]`

I do not want that behavior, the newline is supposed to be part of the former bullet and not a new one. Is there any setting to turn off that "helpfulness" ?   Actually I'm not sure where *any* `markdown` plugin settings live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

`Languages and Frameworks | Markdown | Automatic assistance in the editor` [checkbox]

[image]

After unchecking that box i get this:

```
* analytics services needs to first provide capability of more frequent and timely updates to convince 
  suppliers to provide more timely updates
```

Which is the desired [un-"assisted"] behavior.